# what is the new iOS 7 feature called "swipe to capture"

Tags: ios

On [this site](http://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/) Apple praises the new feature "swipe to capture"

> With a swipe, you can capture what you want the way you want. (2)

And then noting in the footnotes:

> (2.) Square and video formats and swipe to capture are available on
>   iPhone 4 or later, iPad (3rd generation or later), iPad mini, and iPod
>   touch (5th generation).

Now my questions are:

1. What actually is this new iOS 7 feature? How can I use it?
2. Since there is a footnote for this, stating that is not available an all devices, what iOS7-compatible devices do not have this feature?

Comment: "Swipe to capture" is not actually a way of taking a picture so much as the way they redesigned the camera app so you swipe between the modes (normal, video, panoramic, and the new square) instead of tapping on the screen to switch modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS7 update enabled Swipe to Capture – allowing you to switch between camera modes like Photo, Video, Square and Panorama with a swipe.

The iPhone 5, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPad 4, iPad 3, iPad mini, and 5th-gen iPod touch have this feature, while only the iPad 2 does not.